# Permission denied when using Yeoman to scaffold an application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, terminal, npm, yeoman

I am trying to set-up a new project using Yeoman and Angular. I have tried "yo angular" and "yo app" but both times I receive the same error. I am not very experienced with Terminal either.

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/adam/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:438:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:289:15)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:33:29)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:26:44)
    at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:25:17)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/index.js:118:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:146:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

How would I gain access to this file via terminal and be able to scaffold a Yeoman project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution proposed here ?

https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1097